# How do I configure webpack to run bootstrap and sass?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, sass, webpack

I am not great at webpack. I have not really 'learned it', I have a template/boilerplate I pull from a repo I made that gives me an environment to build in React. I am struggling to add bootstrap functionality to my projects because I am not great with webpack and understanding how loaders etc. work. Can someone give me a hand? And maybe a simple explanation about webpack loaders? (It is on my list to learn it, but just not a priority).

I get strange errors like:

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');


var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-camper-leaderboard",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "freecodecamp leaderboard sorter",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "Tim Bell",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^1.0.8",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Checkout the [example from the sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/blob/245ef862b60a364d1bfb3813bd085bbabbff8fe7/test/bootstrapSass/webpack.config.js). Your `webpack.config.js` should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.woff2?$|\.ttf$|\.eot$|\.svg$/,
                loader: "file"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Since you've added a bunch of loaders, you should make sure that all of them are installed:

```
npm i file-loader style-loader css-loader sass-loader --save-dev
```

Then you should add your `main.scss` either as webpack entry to `webpack.config.js`...

```
module.exports = {
   ...
    entry: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'path', 'to',  'main.scss'),
        // add other entries
    ],
    ...
```

... or just require/import it in your `main.js`:

```
require("./path/to/main.scss");
```

Since bootstrap needs its `url()` paths configured, you need to set the `$icon-font-path` **before** importing bootstrap. Your `main.scss` should look like this:

```
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

And if you think `@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";` looks ugly, you can also add an alias to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
   ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "bootstrap-sass$": "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap"
        }
    },
```

Then you just need to write:

```
@import "~bootstrap-sass";
```

Answer (score 1):

Every extension you `import`, `require` or load any other way must have its own loader.

As of `woff2` you might have added something like:

```
{
    test: /\.woff2$/,
    loader: 'url',
    query: {
        limit: 10240,
        name: 'static/[hash].[ext]'
    }
}
```

You might want to check the [`url-loader` documentation](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) about all the parameters it accepts.

You also may match multiple different filename patterns to use with the same loader, eg:

```
{
    test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg|png|gif|woff2?$/,
    loader: 'url',
    query: {
        limit: 10240,
        name: 'static/[hash].[ext]'
    }
}
```

This would load all those extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably something wrong with `./~/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` path. Bootstrap-sass requires it through the sass file but webpack can't find it.

Comment: My bad, I meant webpack. But after fixing this error, he will get the one you wrote about.