# Import Bootstrap 3 CSS into Angular 2+ with SASS as CSS

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, bootstrap-sass

I need to override some things in Bootstrap (3.3.7) CSS, so I need to load Bootstrap before all my other styles in order to do that. I understand  the way to do that is to import it in my application's main `styles.sass` at the top of the document. But when I do this via:

```
@import ./bootstrap.css
```

I get:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css 6:4445-4497 6:4520-4572
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css 6:4622-4676
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css 6:4707-4760
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css 6:4790-4842
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/bootstrap.css 6:4876-4928
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass
```

That didn't work because I didn't bring the fonts into the project.

That made me think there must be a more proper way to install bootstrap.

So then I found [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), and imported it using `npm install bootstrap-sass --save`, and then imported it into `styles.sass` with:

```
@import ../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss
```

And I get:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass 6:4253-4315 6:4338-4400
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass 6:4452-4516
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass 6:4549-4612
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass 6:4644-4706
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg' in '/Users/bradley/Work/dashboard/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles.sass 6:4742-4804
 @ ./src/styles.sass
 @ multi ./src/styles.sass
```

Shouldn't there just be a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've come to learn Bootstrap for Sass has a variable just for this that directs it to where the fonts are. If they were installed with `npm install bootstrap-sass --save`, then you would want to import bootstrap-sass with these two lines at the top of your `styles.sass`:

```
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/"
@import ../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using webpack so you should just look into this thread:

[Bootstrap.sass and Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542283/how-do-i-configure-webpack-to-run-bootstrap-and-sass)